# two tables data comparison if differ need to do update code is excuting continuously it never ends

Tags: oracle

have 2 tables.prod and dev. my requirement I need to compare dev data with prod and if column value is null I need to update as "NULL" as string.

tables have data 1000 rows.

Yes they have the same structure since I will be creating a TEMP tables A with

```
(REVISIONCODE                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60)                
KEY_1                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60) ,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY                    VARCHAR2(60)                
ATTRIBUTE_INDEX                       VARCHAR2(60)                
ATTRIBUTE_STATE                       VARCHAR2(60) ).
A will be compared with B

(REVISIONCODE                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60)                
KEY_1                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60) ,ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY                    VARCHAR2(60)                
ATTRIBUTE_INDEX                       VARCHAR2(60)                
ATTRIBUTE_STATE                       VARCHAR2(60) ).
Here Data A(DEV) is having as

REVISIONCODE        KEY_1                 Category   Index
IN_PROD             360View                         store       
IN_PROD             Alternate display name          Index
IN_PROD             Book product                    store     
Data for B(PROD) is

REVISIONCODE    KEY_1                    Category   Index
IN_PROD       360View                               Store
IN_PROD       Alternate display name        null    Index   
IN_PROD       Book product                          Store
```

here when I look data foreign table B key_1 column Alternate display name category column is having data as "null" where in A same column data is empty.

for that row I need to update table A row data for column category as "null". and one more thing in table A for key_1 360_view category column value is empty in table B also value is empty so I don't need to consider.

for this can you help me efficient way how can I write

I have to compare 12 columns in table.

for this I written code as

```
DECLARE
CURSOR C1 is select * FROM PROD  ;
CURSOR C2 IS select * FROM DEV  ;

     TYPE t_stg_tab IS TABLE OF C1%ROWTYPE;
     c1_var    t_stg_tab   ;

     TYPE t_non_prod_tab IS TABLE OF C2%ROWTYPE;
     c2_var    t_non_prod_tab ;


     v_prod_upd_cntr PLS_INTEGER        := 0;
     l_rec_cnt       NUMBER          := 0;
         start_date      DATE            := sysdate;

BEGIN

OPEN c1;

    FETCH c1   BULK COLLECT INTO c1_var ;
     OPEN c2;
      FETCH c2  BULK COLLECT INTO c2_var ;

    FOR I IN 1..C1_VAR.COUNT LOOP

        FOR J IN 1..C2_VAR.COUNT LOOP

  IF c2_var(j).revisioncode =c1_var(i).revisioncode and c2_var(j).key_1 = c1_var(i).key_1 then
                dbms_output.put_line('c1_var(i).attribute_category'||c1_var(i).attribute_category||'c1_var(i).revisioncode'||c1_var(i).revisioncode||'c2_var(j).key_1'||c2_var(j).key_1);
                dbms_output.put_line('c2_var(j).attribute_category'||c2_var(j).attribute_category||'c2_var(j).revisioncode'||c2_var(j).revisioncode||'c2_var(j).key_1'||c2_var(j).key_1);

                IF c1_var(i).attribute_category is not null then
            IF c1_var(i).attribute_category = 'null' and c2_var(j).attribute_category is null then
                dbms_output.put_line('c2_var(j).attribute_category_empty_need_update'||c2_var(j).attribute_category);
            --    UPDATE P_MD_CE05_ATR_RVSNCD_KEY_TST set attribute_category = 'null' where  revisioncode = c2_var(j).revisioncode and key_1 = c2_var(j).key_1 ;
                        l_update_attribute_category := 'null';
            ELSE
                dbms_output.put_line('c2_var(j).attribute_category_No update'||c2_var(j).attribute_category);
            END IF;
                END IF;
 END IF;

         UPDATE P_MD_CE05_ATR_RVSNCD_KEY_TST set attribute_category = l_update_attribute_category  ;

 l_rec_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
                v_prod_upd_cntr := v_prod_upd_cntr + l_rec_cnt;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NON_PROD_DATA: ' || v_prod_upd_cntr || ' records: starting @ ' || sysdate);
                        DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(start_date||'-up2-'|| v_prod_upd_cntr ||'-'|| sysdate);
END LOOP;


        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after first end loop rowcount_value'||i);

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NON_PROD_DATA: ' || v_prod_upd_cntr || ' records: starting @ ' || sysdate);
                DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(start_date||'-up2-'|| v_prod_upd_cntr ||'-'|| sysdate);
END LOOP;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NON_PROD_DATA: ' || v_prod_upd_cntr || ' records: starting @ ' || sysdate);
        DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(start_date||'-up2-'|| v_prod_upd_cntr ||'-'|| sysdate);
   --   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('at end rowcount_value1'||i||'rowcount2'||j);
Exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_Line('SQLCODE'||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM)  ;

END;
```

When I executed DB not responding.i need to cancel the operation.

Comment: 1000x1000 - 1 million loop iterations.

Comment: how can I update any other alternative please

Comment: also your update statement has no constraint, so all the rows of P_MD_CE05_ATR_RVSNCD_KEY_TST   are getting  over and over.  You need to  re-think the entire design of this.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case your description makes no sense. Try to describe your issue in business terms and then post the actual DDL for your tables. Also provide sample test data - as text and not an image - as well as the expected results from that data.

As for your code it is essentially a NESTED LOOP JOIN and writing it yourself is about the slowest possible way. As indicated you have 1M iterations and you update every row in the target table on each of them.

So write it as JOIN. Oracle has 40+ years working this out and I assure you they are much better at it than either of us. And if appropriately indexed, Oracle may come up with a much better method. The following should implement your loop and `if`  structures (except the update).

```
select c1.*, c2.*
  from prod  c1
  join dev   c2
    on (c2.revisioncode = c1.revivioncode and
        c2.key_1        = c1.key_1
       )
 where c1.attribute_category = 'null'
   and c2.attribute_category is null;
```

The result should give you the same rows that would have passed the `IF` statements and executed the statement `l_update_attribute_category := 'null';`.

The above SQL statement will run standalone but will not run in a procedure block. That is because I've not attempted the update as you have provided no relationship between the tables `Prod`, and/or `Dev`. That is assuming `Prod` and `Dev` refer to **tables** and not environments. (I suspect they are environments.) Revise your question if they are environments.

I am guessing somewhat, but I would guess this can be done in one SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I used your query and procedeeing further.